# How to position an element with position: absolute so that the bottom half of it is hidden below the viewport? Bottom: -50%; doesn't work

Tags: html, css

As you can see in the snippet below, I have an absolutely positioned red circle at the bottom of the page. What I am trying to achieve is to have the top half of the circle visible in the bottom part of the screen whilst having the bottom half hidden from view under the bottom line of the view port.

I felt like doing bottom: -50% would solve my problem, however, that hides more than 70-80% of the circle which is confusing me.

```css
    *, *:after, *:before {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    body {
        background-color: #000;
        color: white;
    }
        .container {
        position: relative;
        height: 100vh;
        width: 100vw;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
        .test-layer8 {
        position: absolute;
        background-color: red;
        border-radius: 50%;
        bottom: -50%;
        width: 500px;
        height: 500px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="container" @mousemove='getCoordinates($event)'>
    <div class="test-layer8"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: if it has a known height, then `bottom:0;margin-bottom:-half-off-the-known-height;`for an unknown height, `bottom:0;transform:translatey(50%)` can do.

Comment: You could also try `bottom: -250px` instead of `bottom: -50%`.

Comment: Thanks a lot @G-Cyr ! Feel free to add this as an answer so I can select it as the correct one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

with absolute position, once element is sent to coordonates, margin or translate  can help reset position at screen:

- `bottom:0;` + `translateY(50%)` might help you here

```css
*, *:after, *:before {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    body {
        background-color: #000;
        color: white;
    }
        .container {
        position: relative;
        height: 100vh;
        width: 100vw;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
        .test-layer8 {
        position: absolute;
        background-color: red;
        border-radius: 50%;
        bottom: 0;
        transform:translateY(50%);
        width: 500px;
        height: 500px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="container" @mousemove='getCoordinates($event)'>
    <div class="test-layer8"></div>
</div>
```

- From a known height : `bottom : 0 ;` + `margin-bottom -x` ; might do too.

```css
*, *:after, *:before {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    body {
        background-color: #000;
        color: white;
    }
        .container {
        position: relative;
        height: 100vh;
        width: 100vw;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
        .test-layer8 {
        position: absolute;
        background-color: red;
        border-radius: 50%;
        bottom: 0;
        margin-bottom:-250px;
        width: 500px;
        height: 500px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="container" @mousemove='getCoordinates($event)'>
    <div class="test-layer8"></div>
</div>
```